# \loop, tabular ignores new row

Tags: tables, loops

I'm trying to get this "timeline" thing going for a document I'm writing. Follows the code I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\addTimeline}[3][]{%
\ifcsname timeLine#2\endcsname
  \expandafter\appto\csname timeLine#2\endcsname{ #3 #1\\}
\else
  \expandafter\csdef{timeLine#2}{{\bf #2}  #3  #1\\}
\fi
}

\newcommand{\gentimeLine}[2]{
\newcount\tmpc
\def\tabledata{}
\tmpc=#1
\loop \ifnum \tmpc<#2 
   \expandafter\csuse{timeLine\the\tmpc}
   \advance \tmpc 1
\repeat 
}

\begin{document}

\addTimeline{10}{Test1}
\addTimeline{20}{Test2}
\addTimeline{13}{Test3}
\addTimeline{25}{Test4}

\def\tabData{\gentimeLine{1}{26}}
\tabData

-

\begin{tabular}{c}\hline   
  \tabData
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Naturally, in `\addTimeline` command I intend to have `#2 & #3 & #1` and `{c c c}` in tabular instead, but for testing purposes I am keeping it in one column one.

The expected output was

```
10 Test1
13 Test3
20 Test2
25 Test4
```

followed by the table with those entries, each in a respective row.

But instead I get a table with only one row, containing the first entry `10 Test1`. The 4 items are correctly printed in normal text, however.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please add to your code the `\documentclass` and anything else that would be needed for it to be compiled for experimentation.  otherwise, we'd have to guess, and if we make the wrong choice, that's effort wasted.

Answer (score 3):

You can't start the loop in one table cell and end it in another one. Thus I use `\tabledata` as a container that's filled and then delivers the table body all at once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\addTimeline}[3][]{%
  \csappto{timeLine#2}{\unexpanded{\textbf{#2}  #3  #1\\}}%
}

\newcount\tmpc
\newcommand{\gentimeLine}[2]{%
  \def\tabledata{}%
  \tmpc=#1\relax
  \loop \ifnum \tmpc<#2
    \edef\tabledata{\expandonce{\tabledata}\csuse{timeLine\the\tmpc}}%
    \advance \tmpc 1
  \repeat
  \tabledata
}

\begin{document}

\addTimeline{10}{Test1}
\addTimeline{20}{Test2}
\addTimeline{13}{Test3}
\addTimeline{25}{Test4}

\def\tabData{\gentimeLine{1}{26}}

\begin{tabular}{c}\hline
  \tabData
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Notes

1. `etoolbox` already offers `\csappto` that will create the macro if not existing
2. `\newcount` must go outside the macro using the counter, or it will create a new one at each call
3. the `\unexpanded` in the definition of `\addTimeline` might be bad for other uses of `timeLine<number>`

Here's the output:

[image]

An implementation in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addTimeline}{omm}
 {
  \tl_clear_new:c { l_benedict_timeline_#2_tl }
  \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#2_tl } { \textbf{#2}~#3 }
  \IfValueT{#1}
   {
    \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#2_tl } { ~#1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#2_tl } { \\ }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\genTimeline}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \tl_if_exist:cT { l_benedict_timeline_##1_tl }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nv \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl { l_benedict_timeline_##1_tl }
     }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn { Nv }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addTimeline{10}{Test1}
\addTimeline{20}{Test2}
\addTimeline[again]{20}{Test2}
\addTimeline{13}{Test3}
\addTimeline{25}{Test4}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
\genTimeline{1}{26}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]